# How can I change TIMESTAMP to TIMESTAMP(3)?

Tags: mysql, alter-table, timestamp

I have a column of `TIMESTAMP`, `NOT NULL`, `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

I want to modify it as `TIMESTAMP(3)`.

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE <table>
MODIFY COLUMN <column>
TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

And I got.

> Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for '<column>'

What can I do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering for my own question.

I found an answer solves the exact problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23671577/330457

Shortly, I needed to specify the same type for `DEFAULT`.

```
ALTER TABLE <table>
MODIFY COLUMN <column>
TIMESTAMP(3)
NOT NULL
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) -- See?
```

Comment: It's good that you were able to do so. Could you also please mark it as accepted so that others seeking to resolve similar problems can quickly get an answer. You might have to wait? Also, no points :-) - that would be too easy!